# Error when I call a method inside a class

Tags: php

I have a method to check if a day is Saturday or Sunday :

```
private static function isweekend($year, $month, $day)
    {
                    $time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
                    $weekday = date('w', $time);
                    return ($weekday == 0 || $weekday == 6);
    }
```

I call it like that :

```
$samedi_ou_dimanche = isweekend($annee,$mois,$jour);
```

I have this error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function isweekend() in /home/web1196/public_html/classes/Calendrier.class.php on line 268

The code above is inside a class :

```
class Calendrier
{
    private $db; // instance PDO

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = PDO2::getInstance()->db;
    }
...

$samedi_ou_dimanche = isweekend($annee,$mois,$jour);
     echo $samedi_ou_dimanche;

        $html .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td id=\"AM_". $annee . '_' . $mois . '_' . $jour . "\" class=\"statutPeriode $statutAm";
        if ($_SESSION['utilisateur']->getRang() == "administrateur" || $statutAm == "libre" || ($statutAm == "proposé" && $idAm == $_SESSION['utilisateur']->getId())) $html .= $editable . $commentStatutAm;
        else $html .= $commentStatutAm;
        $html .= "\" style=\"background-color:$colorAm;\">$am</td>\n";
        $html .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr>\n";

        // P.M.
        $html .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr>\n";
        $html .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td class=\"periode\">P.M.</td>\n";
        $html .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<td id=\"PM_". $annee . '_' . $mois . '_' . $jour . "\" class=\"statutPeriode $statutPm";
        if ($_SESSION['utilisateur']->getRang() == "administrateur" || $statutPm == "libre" || ($statutPm == "proposé" && $idPm == $_SESSION['utilisateur']->getId())) $html .= $editable . $commentStatutPm;
        else $html .= $commentStatutPm;
        $html .= "\" style=\"background-color:$colorPm;\">$pm</td>\n";
        $html .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</tr>\n";


        $html .= "\t\t\t\t\t\t</table>\n";

        // affichage des données de debug
        $debug .= ob_get_clean();
        // $html .= "<div class=\"debug\">$debug&nbsp;</div>";

        return $html;
    }

    private static function isweekend($year, $month, $day)
    {
                    $time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);
                    $weekday = date('w', $time);
                    return ($weekday == 0 || $weekday == 6);
    }

}
```

Comment: the function is inside the class, I have to include it ?

Comment: Try to call  `$samedi_ou_dimanche = self::isweekend($annee,$mois,$jour);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the same class, use:

```
$samedi_ou_dimanche = self::isweekend($annee,$mois,$jour);
```

recommended reading [Classes and Objects Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: is it possible to check if saturday or sunday ?  I would like only to add a disable if it's one of those days.

Comment: Why? It's not needed to change visibility. Just need to call `$samedi_ou_dimanche = self::isweekend($annee,$mois,$jour);`

Comment: @PiotrOlaszewski if it is in the same class

Comment: @SimoneNigro In example call is from the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$samedi_ou_dimanche = Calandrier::isweekend($annee,$mois,$jour);
```